# C++/Win32 messsage pump program flow when step in/through

Tags: c++, winapi

So I have beginners knowledge of C++ (4 months daily study, so maybe slightly more than beginner but definitely very new) and I have started looking at some win API stuff and have a few blanks in my head.

I am sure there are many things wrong with the below, or better ways to do it, and that will come in time but I'd like to know why when I step through this code does it for instance loop a few times through the first WndProc definition before passing the control elsewhere, and seemingly cease to ever come into contact with other parts of the program.

Is windows looping through the code to check for events at high speed then moving control else where?

I am sure with your knowledge you may want  to even correct my question, so all information that you find related to what I think I'm asking here is appreciated.

Forgive the comments, they're to future self ;)

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <string>

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam ) 
{
    switch (msg) 
    {
    case WM_CLOSE:
        PostQuitMessage(69);
        break;
    }

    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
}


int CALLBACK WinMain( 
    HINSTANCE hInstance,
    HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    LPSTR   lpCmdLine,
    int nCmdShow)
{
    const auto CLASSNAME = "hwWindow";  

        //register window class
    WNDCLASSEX wc = {};
    wc.cbSize = sizeof(wc);
    wc.style = CS_OWNDC;
    wc.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wc.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wc.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wc.hInstance = nullptr;
    wc.hIcon = nullptr;
    wc.hCursor =nullptr;
    wc.hbrBackground = nullptr;
    wc.lpszMenuName = nullptr;
    wc.lpszClassName = CLASSNAME;
    wc.hIconSm = nullptr;
    RegisterClassEx(&wc);
        //create window instance

    HWND RyanWin = CreateWindowEx(
        0,
        CLASSNAME,
        "Hacker",
        WS_CAPTION | WS_MINIMIZEBOX | WS_SYSMENU,
        1200, 1200, 640, 480,
        nullptr,
        nullptr,
        hInstance,
        nullptr);

    HWND hWnd = CreateWindowEx(
        0,
        CLASSNAME,
        "Happy HW Windows",
        WS_CAPTION | WS_MINIMIZEBOX | WS_SYSMENU,
        200, 200, 640, 480,
        nullptr,
        nullptr,
        hInstance,
        nullptr);


        ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_SHOW);
        ShowWindow(RyanWin , SW_SHOW);

        MSG msg;
        BOOL gResult;

        while ((gResult = GetMessage(&msg, nullptr, 0, 0)) > 0)
        {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);

            UINT m = msg.message; 
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }

        if (gResult == -1) { return -1; }

        else { return msg.wParam; }


                return 0;
    }
```

Comment: [About Messages and Message Queues](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/about-messages-and-message-queues).

Comment: The calls you make to `GetMessage()` and `DispatchMessage()` can result in your `WndProc` being called.

Comment: so the program still 'starts' at the WinMain entry point? Thanks for comments, I think it's helped - 7am here though, bed time soon.

Comment: Go read [this book](https://www.amazon.com/Programming-Windows%C2%AE-Fifth-Developer-Reference/dp/157231995X/) .  It will explain everything.

Comment: Is there an equivalent book with C++ as this looks like its using intermediate C. Also why do you recommend this specifically - I have been looking at one and so it'd be nice to have an idea before I pay. I'm unemployed due to poor health. It's over 20 years old and I don't want to get it just because some people don't like new. lol. That aside im happy to check out a classic if its going to help and be modern.

Comment: Thanks for other comments I missed and links - still getting used to this.

Comment: Read Petzold's book. It's the one. It was the right book when we all learnt Win32, and it remains so today.

Comment: The Windows API has a C interface. There's no C++ book on the Windows API. Jeffrey Richter's *"Windows via C/C++"* doesn't actually use C++. And yes, Petzold's book is still the resource to learn the Windows API. Most of it is still relevant today; just skip over the section that covers device-dependent bitmaps.

Comment: Okay, I will put it on order this month. Thank you. Any online equivalents in the meantime?